# Duplicate Slide in PHPPresentation

Tags: php, phppresentation

Can't find any information on this feature on the github repo or stackoverflow.

Does anyone know if you can duplicate a slide with various shapes (charts, tables, textboxes etc) using PHPPresentation?

If this is possible, as there any limitations? e.g. does not copy the colour/theme?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else needed an answer to this question...

I managed to run this duplicate functionality using phppresentation and its very restricted. It does not copy the themes, colors, any type of formatting, charts.

Comment: hi, have u got any solution. here?